# Update two columns with same SUM and Group BY

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to update with the value in this query, but it's saying errors... and i'm trying to minimize it.

```
update p
set a10=t.sumgc
from temp as p inner join 
(SELECT     SUM(gcsanad) as sumgc,good_gr
fROM         dbo.fgoodgroup 
WHERE     (flag = 2)
group by good_gr ) as t
on t.good_gr=p.a3
,
a11=t.sumgc
from temp as p inner join 
(SELECT     SUM(gcsanad) as sumgc,good_gr
fROM         dbo.fgoodgroup 
WHERE     (flag = 4) 
group by good_gr ) as t
on t.good_gr=p.a3
```

Comment: Hi Bahador, welcome to SO. It's totally not a good idea to write your name in Persian dude, other's may have difficulty reading your name.

Comment: I have no idea what to call him - @MahdiTahsildari I was about to call him "Snakes"

Comment: Hahaha :) @Aniket His name in English is BahadorBaradaran

Comment: that's a nice name :-) thanks @MahdiTahsildari

Comment: check the solution it might work for you..

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
update p
set a10=t.sumgc
,
a11=t.sumgc1

from temp as p inner join 
(SELECT 
  (case when  flag = 2 then   SUM(gcsanad)  end) as sumgc,
  (case when  flag = 4 then   SUM(gcsanad)  end) as sumgc1
fROM         dbo.fgoodgroup 
group by good_gr ) as t
on t.good_gr=p.a3
```